# How to pass form parameters to Action class when opening a jsp in a new window through Javascript

Tags: javascript, struts2

Below is the Javascript function call in which I am calling a struts action which in turn resolves to a jsp .In the Jsp page which is opened in a separate window I have a form with a few text boxes and drop down and a submit button.When I submit the filled form I am unable to get all these form fields although those instance variables are defined in the action class.Is there something that i am missing here????

```
function editQuestions(val) {
    window.open("fetchQuestionAction.action?"+
        "quesId="+val,'mywindow','width=400,height=200');
}
```

Comment: You don't `open jsp pages` in Struts2. You (the browser) opens a url that is mapped to an action that shows (typically) a jsp. I cannot understand what you are doing. Perhaps you should include some schema (urls, actions, jsp) involved.

Comment: You should have given the code of the child window in the queston.What exactly the error you are getting?Have you tried Mark Guk's second option?

Answer (score 1):

For get the data in the new window you can:

1. POST the data to the Different action that will put it to the session. Then open the window. The POST action should be done via AJAX to not reload the page unneccessary.
2. Add the data from the Form fields to the query string for the URI for the window.open first parameter. Then you could use this data on the server to render the new page or just send it in hidden fields and use on the client.

Comment: I am on a parent JSP from which am calling a child JSP using window.open and am submitting the child jsp but am unable to extract the form fields of child jsp in action class

Comment: Looks like you missing something. When you open the new "JSP" by window.open() - you perform that on the client. So when the child page is rendered you got the Child-Action called. As this page havent been submitted by the User, you got nothing in the Child-Action. 
Looks like your problem not in the window.open, but in the JSP itself, so the Struts not got the POST parameters set to the Action class?

Comment: I am able to post my form field into the action class and do mu update in DB.But the problem is how and where can I close the opened window as I don't need it after the form is submitted.Rather the window should be autoclosed after form submitted

Comment: @Sam:So do that: 
After making changed in the DB send the JSP with the JavaScript that will close the window for you by calling `window.close()`. http://blogs.x2line.com/al/articles/350.aspx
Note also, that the `window.close` works perfectly only in windows that opened by `window.open`. So in your case it fits your needs as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Can you read the data from the form fields and append them as request params to the URL. This way the params should be available on the opened window.